# What is the difference between a script and custom function in GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This may be a stupid question, but I haven't been able to find the difference clearly outlined in the GAS documentation, and I was wondering what is qualified as a script vs a custom function. I have a Google Sheet that requires a function to run on an edit that checks whether the values entered already exist on another page (many line items are entered at once with a copy/paste and currently the script goes line by line to determine if a unique identifier from each line already exists on one of two other sheets, deleting any duplicates as it goes). I call this function from onEdit(), and on average it seems to take 30-40 seconds to run.

This is where I run into my problem, as the time limit for a custom function to run is 30 seconds, whereas scripts can run for 5 minutes. I should plan for my data set to grow, and therefore need this process to run as a script so that it doesn't cut off halfway through. I thought that onEdit() and anything you call from it qualified as a script and not a custom function, but clearly this is not the case. How do you make a script vs a function?

EDIT: Not sure why, but creating a manual trigger that calls onEdit on an edit seems to run it as a script, whereas the implicit onEdit call that is built in is called as a custom function. This fixed my immediate problem, but if anyone has an explanation of the difference I would still greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is that a **custom function** is called by entering `=functionName()` into a cell on the spreadsheet. Also, a custom function must return a value to be displayed in the cell. See the [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#return_values).

The example below from the same documentation I linked above is an example of a **custom function**. The custom function is called by entering (for example) `=DOUBLE(5)` in a cell on the spreadsheet. The function will run taking the `input` parameter (5) and multiplying it by 2, it will then return the answer (10) and display this value in the spreadsheet cell.

```
function DOUBLE(input) {
  return input * 2;
}
```

However, your `onEdit()` function is called by means of a trigger be it a simple trigger, installed trigger, custom menu button or the run button in the script editor and it doesn't require that a value be returned to the main function.

If you try to type `=onEdit()` into a cell on your spreadsheet the function won't run and you will receive an error in the cell.